# Reading lines from a file into variables in Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I'm creating a script to automate adding users from a text file in Unix using Bash

I've read a file into a script which is being held in $FILE

The file is in the following format:
e-mail;birthdate;groups;sharedFolder

I want to ignore the first line in the file and read the data into variables

I have already set the IFS to ';' earlier. Currently I have

```
sed 1d $FILE | while read EMAIL BIRTH GROUPS SHAREDFOLDER
do
echo "$EMAIL"
done < $FILE
```

But when I echo out the EMAIL variable, I get nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to redirect standard input twice. The pipeline and the `<` can't both be connected to `while read`. On my Bash the `<` wins:

```
bash$ echo moo | cat <<<bar
bar
```

Apparently you want simply

```sh
sed 1d "$FILE" | while read -r EMAIL BIRTH GROUPS SHAREDFOLDER
do
    echo "$EMAIL"
done
```

though this can meaningfully be reduced to just

```
sed 1d;s/;.*//' "$FILE"
```

You also really want to [use lower case for your private variables](/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization), but that's a separate discussion.

Comment: For some reason, I still get no output from echo, even using your method.

If I only add one variable to my read statement, then echo out that variable, it echos out each line. It's almost like the IFS isn't splitting on ";"

Comment: @Ali97 Does `sed '1d;s/;.*//' "$FILE"` outputs anything?

Comment: Or are you trying to access the variable outside the loop? That won't work in many scenarios; see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: I'm unsure what the cause of the issue was, but with the EXACT same statement, if I changed my variables to lowercase, it worked perfectly fine.

I'll mark this answer as correct as it was the most comprehensive and did make mention about variables being lowercase

Comment: Just seen that there is an environmental variable called "GROUPS". They were probably clashing. I assume this is why private variables should be lowercase

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I'll add a link.

Comment: @Ali97 Apparently bash version 4 (and probably 5) treats an attempt to `read` to the `GROUPS` special variable as an error (and `read` getting an error exits the loop).